# wp_head not working in plugin

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

I've written a simple plugin for my own use and I'm trying to insert some javascript into the head tag.

If I use

```
add_action( 'init', 'add_to_head' );
```

Then it works, but it loads before any Jquery does which is no good.

If I use

```
add_action( 'wp_head', 'add_to_head' );
```

Then nothing happens at all! 
This is the function I'm trying to call.

```
function add_to_head() {?> 
<script>alert("test");</script><?php
}
```

There's no errors in the console unless I use the add_action 'init' which says Jquery is not defined (obviously).

**Update**

If I use add_action( 'get_footer', 'add_to_head' ); then it works! But I'm not sure if this is the right hook to use.

Answer (score 0):

Use `wp_footer` hook, there is nothing wrong to use `wp_footer` hook.

```
<?php
function add_to_head() {?> 
    <script>alert("test");</script><?php
}
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'add_to_head' );
?>
```

Comment: I should of mentioned that I also tried this hook, this doesn't work either

Answer (score 0):

Try to give priority so that your code will add before

```
function mycustom_enqueue() {     
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('1');</script>";
}
add_action( 'wp_head', 'mycustom_enqueue',100 );
//here 100 is prioriry
```

Comment: This will make it run later. If you want it to run before others, then it should be a number lower than 10 (which is the default).